# MySql equivalent `IN()` query in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

I would like to get all entry that country code is `US` or `CA`. I prepare my query by the following way but getting zero number or records instead of having te records by country code `US` and `CA`

**Way 1**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "bool" : {
         "filter" : {
            "terms" : {
              "country_code" : ["CA","US"]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Way 2**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "bool" : {
         "must" : {
            "terms" : {
              "country_code" : ["CA","US"]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Could you please help me to find out my fault in query?

Comment: Can you post mapping of my_index; My gues is try using ```GET my_index/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "bool" : {
         "must" : {
            "terms" : {
              "country_code" : ["ca","us"]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}``` .Moslty you are using standard analyzer and using term query. So term ignores the analyzers. Check `Why doesn’t the term query match my document?` in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution by using lowercase

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {"terms": {"country_code": ["us","ca"]}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```